# Statistically independent probability train question

Tags: probability

Statistically independent probability question (repost of my other one which I didn't include enough information)

The question says: A survey found that 40% of late trains were late in May and that 15% were late on the 15th day of a given month. Also, it was found that 4% of late trains were late on the 15th day of May.

1) What is the probability that a train is late in May but not on the 15th day.

2) Are the events 'Train late in May' and 'Train late on the 15th day of a month' statistically independent?

My attempt:

P(A): May =0.4

P(B): 15th day of a month =0.15

A∩B=0.04

I thought the answer to 1) was 0.4−0.04=0.36; however, I'm not sure whether the other days in the month are relevant

For 2) I did 0.4×0.15=0.06; Since 0.06≠0.04 they are not statistically independent.

Are both these answers correct, or is there something I've missed?

Comment: To start, your 'universe' is late trains, so simplify everything by leaving out 'late train'. Then $P(May) = .4,\,$ $P(15th) = .15,\,$ and $P(May \cap 15th) = .04.$ And so on. You seem to be on the right track.

Comment: So for q1 would 0.4-0.04=0.36 be the correct answer? If not, what has been done wrong?

Comment: Seems right to me. Also the 'not independent' part.

Comment: Ok thats good, thank you for your help